# Execute .py file with C++

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to execute a .py file, made a simple c++ loader, which is working with the "PyRun_SimpleString" command.

The problem is when I'm trying to load that script into another application that doesn't have this "PyRun_SimpleString" or any "PyRun_***" command.
How could I execute that .py file?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) might be useful.

Comment: There are two ways of "running" any generic script (Python or other): Either embed the script engine, which is what you're practically doing when you use `PyRun_SimpleString`; The second way is to invoke the command-line script runner command, in your case the `python` command, and pass the script to it. Which you should use depends on your use case and what you need to do with the result of the script.

Comment: By linking that application with the Python library?

Comment: It won't help me because it will just open it with my default .py editor. @ Karen

I've already done this, but I've already mentioned "PyRun_SimpleString" command doesn't exists in the file I'm trying to load the script. @Some programmer dude

Could explain me how and what should I do? @ user253751

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the system() command:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    system("python yourScriptFile.py");
    return 0;
}
```

Please note, that the `return 0` will be executed after returning from `yourScriptFile.py` (after the python script ends).

Comment: Tried it and doesn't seem to work.
It will not "import" my script.

Comment: two things you need to do: 1) make sure when you execute `python` that you can run it from any folder (else you need to specify the full path or setup the PATH global OS variable). 2) make sure that the execute c binary file, which invokes the python script, located at the same folder of the `yourScriptFile.py` script file.

Comment: @0x00BAD: please send your error messages and the printout. Also try to send any principle code/example that you use and it doesn't work. Finally, you mentioned that the `PyRun_SimpleString` is working - please show this working example :-)

Comment: PyRun_String("execfile('C:/test.py',{})", NULL, NULL, NULL);
That's my code that works (on the binary that is using functions from python27.dll, not the one that has it built in)